# Login authentication fails in laravel 4

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

In Laravel4,I have written the following code in routes but it always redirect me to login page.
I have googled and found it on stack overflow too and tried all solutions but not succeeded.I am sure it would be a silly mistake but kindly track it out.Thank You

Routes:

```
Route::post('login', function ()
    {
            $user = array(
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'))
    );
            /* Store entered username and password in an array named as 'user' */
            print_r($user);

            if (Auth::attempt($user)) 
            {
                return Redirect::route('home')->with('flash_notice', 'You are successfully logged in.');
                /* Authentication Success!!..Redirect user to home page */
            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect::route('login')
                    ->with('flash_error', 'Your username/password combination was incorrect.')->withInput();
                            /* Authentication failure!! lets go back to the login page */
            }
    });
```

User Model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface 
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    // public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * The primary key of the table.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }



/**
 * Get the unique identifier for the user.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->getKey();
}

/**
 * Get the password for the user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
```

}

User Seeder:

```
<?php
class UserSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
         DB::table('users')->delete();
        return array('table'=>'users',
        array(
                'username' => 'admin',
                'password' => 'admin'
         ),
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you ask the Auth class to attempt a login, you pass in the username and pass as it is. But if you look into the method, it will first hash the password to make it secure and then match it with database entry. When you are storing it, from your present implementation, its not hashed.

As suggested above, you should make this change in your seeder:

```
array(
    'username' => 'admin',
    'password' => Hash::make('password')
),
```

Although I am not very sure if the way you are using seeder is correct by syntax, but if it works, just hash the password there.

Answer (score 0):

You should hash your password.

```
array(
    'username' => 'admin',
    'password' => Hash::make('password')
),
```

You can find more information in [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/security#storing-passwords).

Comment: Thank You all
but I finally got the error
dont use hash::make password in auth::attempt
(as once I have hashed in seeder)

Comment: @Navya, how did you solve your problem? I'm in a similar situation.