# Laravel Auth::atempt keeps failing

Tags: oauth, laravel, laravel-4

I am using this code to authenticate user with Facebook and laravel-oauth2 package. But my Auth::atempt keeps failing.(Ecos FLAG) Can someone help me see the problem ? Here is my controller function and code for my route:

```
Route::get('oauth/{provider}', 'HomeController@provide');

public function provide($provider)
{

       $init_p = $provider;

            $provider = OAuth2::provider($provider, array(
            'id' => 'MY ID',
            'secret' => 'MY SECRET',
        ));

    if ( ! isset($_GET['code']))
    {

        return $provider->authorize();
    }
    else
    {

        try
        {
            $params = $provider->access($_GET['code']);

                $token = new Token_Access(array(
                    'access_token' => $params->access_token
                ));
                $provided_user = $provider->get_user_info($token);


            if($init_p == 'facebook')
            {
                    if (User::whereFacebookUid($provided_user['uid'])->first())
                    {


                        if(Auth::check())
                        {
                            return Redirect::to('/testovi');
                        }
                        else
                        {


                            if (Auth::attempt(array('password' => $provided_user['uid'])))
                            {
                                return Redirect::to('/testovi');
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo("FLAG");
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $user = new User;
                        $user->name = $provided_user['name'];
                        $user->email = $provided_user['email'];
                        $user->password = $provided_user['uid'];
                        $user->facebook_uid = $provided_user['uid'];
                        $user->save();

                        Auth::login($user);
                        return Redirect::to('testovi');

                    }



            }
        }

        catch (OAuth2_Exception $e)
        {
            show_error('That didnt work: '.$e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You're trying to attempt a login with the users Facebook UID? Fairly sure you'll need a `username` and `password` combination for the `attempt` method. So you're going to have to pass in both credentials for it to authenticate correctly.

Comment: I am newbie. Trying to figure it out.

Comment: When I use Auth::attempt(array('username'=>$provided_user['name'],'password' => $provided_user['uid']) I get FLAG again

Comment: I'm not really sure why you're trying to use the Facebook UID as the password though? Is that the users password? Also it needs to be the unhashed password as Laravel's Auth library will compare the hashed password in the database to the unhashed password you provide in the `attempt` method.

Comment: I dont know the best way to implement passwordless authentication. I am using facebok uid and storing it in filed called password. (Bad naming) With that I differentiate users.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to HASH uid befor saving id to db. Details from:

[Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417332/login-authentication-fails-in-laravel-4)

```
$user = new User;
$user->username = $provided_user['name'];
$user->email = $provided_user['email'];
$user->password = Hash::make($provided_user['uid']);
$user->facebook_uid = $provided_user['uid'];
$user->save();
Auth::login($user);
return Redirect::to('testovi');
```